# Using RPC to spawn my player

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, monodevelop, photon

In my project, I have two prefabs - One with a first person camera, and another one stripped of all it's first person components such as the mouselook, input controller, camera, and so on.  My ultimate goal is to spawn my prefab with the camera on it and sending an rpc to spawn the dummy prefab on all other clients to sync up with my first person prefab. The problem I'm facing is when I try to send the rpc from my first person prefab's PhotonView, the rpc doesn't get called on other clients because the PhotonView id doesn't exist on other clients yet.

The following code is located on my NetworkManager script on an empty game object in the hierarchy.

```
void OnJoinedRoom(){
    GameObject MyPlayer = (GameObject) Instantiate (FPSPlayer,spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.rotation);
    FPSPlayerPhotonView = MyPlayer.transform.root.gameObject.GetPhotonView();
    int id = PhotonNetwork.AllocateViewID ();
    FPSPlayerPhotonView.viewID = id;
    FPSPlayerPhotonView.RPC("SpawnMyPlayerAsRemote", PhotonTargets.OthersBuffered,id, spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.rotation);
}

[PunRPC]
void SpawnMyPlayerAsRemote(int id, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot){
    GameObject MyRemotePlayer = (GameObject)Instantiate (RemotePlayer, pos,rot);
    RemotePlayerPhotonView = MyRemotePlayer.transform.root.gameObject.GetPhotonView();
    RemotePlayerPhotonView.viewID = id;
}
```

[image: damnit, damnit, damnit, damnit, damnit]

Comment: Does PhotonView object you call RPC on has SpawnMyPlayerAsRemote method in one of the attached scripts? If not, you should get errors in log when calling such RPC.

Answer (score 0):

This method is tested and will work.

What I suggest you do is create an empty player with NetworkView.

Create this player via **PhotonNetwork.Instantiate** so it will be instantiated inside all clients.

Check you are the owner of the networkview.
If you are, create all the client sided essentials (FPS Camera etc...).
If you aren't, create the dummy.

---

**EDIT: I was wrong on the RPC part.**